# Why multiline TextView and two single line TextView's height is different?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to synchronize these views

1. Two TextView

[image: Image1]

2. One TextView with two lines

[image: Image2]

Two TextView's height is 73 * 2 = 146

But, One TextView is 155.

I want to show same layout for these views.

Why these views are different?

Here is my code

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5.5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey900"
        android:textSize="15.5sp" />
```

Comment: because you set android:lineSpacingExtra="5.5dp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it includes some situation,

1. different padding
2. different margin
3. different lines-pacing

as above will make `different total height` with them.

---

In case 1
You use two TextView, total height depends on

`textHeight*2 + padding-bottom*2 + padding-top*2 + margin-between-them`

---

In case 2
You use single multiline TextView, total height depends on

`textHeight*2 + padding-bottom + paddingTop + line-spacing`

---

You can see that `variables` make different height are `padding`、`margin`、`line-spacing`